# Do I need Django-2.0.checksum.txt to check if the downloaded tar.gz is not malware ?

Tags: command-line, tar, django, pgp

I am a newbie in Ubuntu and bash.
I want to install Django on my Ubuntu 14.04 by typing bash commands in the terminal.
I downloaded Django latest release from here https://www.djangoproject.com/download/

Now I need to unpack this tar.gz and install it. The file Django-2.0.checksum.txt is on the webpage https://www.djangoproject.com/download/ as well (the right side of the page).

I am not sure whether I need to use the file Django-2.0.checksum.txt for security purposes. I don't know what to do. If I don't use this file and start to install the unpacked file.tar.gz, will my Ubuntu be at risk? Is it possible that this tar.gz contain malicious code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checksum value is used to verify the integrity of the file you download from the Web. So here integrity comes about so many things. But as an example due to bad internet connection assume your download was cancelled and you have download the file later with some packets of data missing in it, then you will never succeed installing Django with that file because it is "corrupted".

So to save your time, once you have downloaded the file its always better practice to verify the checksum of the file provided by Website with checksum of the file downloaded at your end.

For more information, you may read below content. 
Source: https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChAdvChecksums.html

> Checksums are used to ensure the integrity of data portions for data
>   transmission or storage. A checksum is basically a calculated summary
>   of such a data portion.
>
> Network data transmissions often produce errors, such as toggled,
>   missing or duplicated bits. As a result, the data received might not
>   be identical to the data transmitted, which is obviously a bad thing.
>
> Because of these transmission errors, network protocols very often use
>   checksums to detect such errors. The transmitter will calculate a
>   checksum of the data and transmits the data together with the
>   checksum. The receiver will calculate the checksum of the received
>   data with the same algorithm as the transmitter. If the received and
>   calculated checksums don’t match a transmission error has occurred.
>
> Some checksum algorithms are able to recover (simple) errors by
>   calculating where the expected error must be and repairing it.
>
> If there are errors that cannot be recovered, the receiving side
>   throws away the packet. Depending on the network protocol, this data
>   loss is simply ignored or the sending side needs to detect this loss
>   somehow and retransmits the required packet(s).
>
> Using a checksum drastically reduces the number of undetected
>   transmission errors. However, the usual checksum algorithms cannot
>   guarantee an error detection of 100%, so a very small number of
>   transmission errors may remain undetected.
>
> There are several different kinds of checksum algorithms; an example
>   of an often used checksum algorithm is CRC32. The checksum algorithm
>   actually chosen for a specific network protocol will depend on the
>   expected error rate of the network medium, the importance of error
>   detection, the processor load to perform the calculation, the
>   performance needed and many other things.

Comment: Note that checksums can only be used to detect accidental corruption-someone who can conduct an MITM attack to send you a malicious archive can also replace the checksum file with one that matches the malicious archive.

Comment: Thanks. So checksums are not intended to detect a trojan, virus, cryptocurrency mining code hidden in downloaded files, etc., right? They are aimed at finding errors which occurred during data transmission in most cases.

Comment: Do you think it is unlikely that the Django release 2.0 contains any viruses on https://www.djangoproject.com/download/?

Comment: @user18146 I just want to know, what makes you think like an official Django release had virus or malicious content in it ?

Comment: I can't figure out whether this site https://www.djangoproject.com/download/ is a trustablel source . I don't know how they protect their official release from malicious attacks. I've read that Django developers are volunteers, and Dango is an open-source framework. How do they ensure security as to Django in the context of viruses?

Comment: Then you better ask this question to them directly.

Comment: I've already installed it. I hope Django latest release taken from this site meets my expectations.